# Update table set same value to all rows with duplicate value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of sport results. When using following code, the table get places according to the times.

```
SET @pos := 0;
UPDATE table SET Place = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 ) ORDER BY Time ASC;
```

In case of same times (like rows 1,3 and 4,5), it updates it according to the ID-s, so the result is following:

```
ID | Time     | Place
1  | 00:12:14 | 1
2  | 00:12:18 | 3
3  | 00:12:14 | 2
4  | 00:12:25 | 4
5  | 00:12:25 | 5
```

How could I update the table so, that if there is multiple rows of same time, all rows would get the best place (like in following table)?

```
ID | Time     | Place
1  | 00:12:14 | 1
2  | 00:12:18 | 3
3  | 00:12:14 | 1
4  | 00:12:25 | 4
5  | 00:12:25 | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a join of the table to a query returning for each row the number of rows less than its Time:

```
update tablename t inner join (
  select t.id, (
    select count(*) counter from tablename
    where time < t.time
  ) counter
  from tablename t
) c on c.id = t.id
set t.place = c.counter + 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m8xrLRQaKPPgncfdAibDNW/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Time     | Place |
| --- | -------- | ----- |
| 1   | 00:12:14 | 1     |
| 2   | 00:12:18 | 3     |
| 3   | 00:12:14 | 1     |
| 4   | 00:12:25 | 4     |
| 5   | 00:12:25 | 4     |
```